# How do I make claim environment bold?

Tags: environments

I have defined my claim environment in the following way:

```
\newcounter{claimcounter}
\newenvironment{claim}{\stepcounter{claimcounter}{Claim \theclaimcounter:}}{}
```

It looks like this:

> Claim 1

How can I make it to look like this:
**Claim 1**?

Answer (score 3):

You really ought to use a theorem-like construction instead.

```
\newtheorem{claim}{Claim}
```

will by default give you want you want.